# Wifi on hp Omen 16b0

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp

So, I've just installed kubuntu on my omen laptop and everything works fine, but the only way I can connect to the internet is using an ethernet cable. The wifi option doesn't even show up. I tried doing a `ifconfig` to see if my wifi card was there but it wasn't there.
I know that the wifi card is from intel.

I suspect it's some kind of driver issue, but i really don't know what to do at this point.

I'm currently dual booting windows with ubuntu and on windows the card works fine.

here's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
0000:2e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    DeviceName: Intel Wireless LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after restarting the problem solved itself. It's also worth mentioning that it was the first time I booted ubuntu on this computer, so maybe it needed a restart.
Now everything works fine.

Comment: Possibly helpful:https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).